# Parsing a string with spaces into tags-input (each string as a tag) - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to paste a copied string into tags-input element, such as:
"a@gmail.com b@gmail.com c@gmail.com d@gmail.com":

[image]

and once I go out of focus (from the tags-input element), I want the result to be:

[image]

Right now, the actual result is:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

My code looks like that:

```
<label for="txt_emails" class="col-md-2 custom-share-email">{{'EMAILS' | translate}}</label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 pull-left form-group">
                <tags-input ng-model="emails" id="txt_emails" type="email" placeholder="{{'EMAILS' | translate}}" replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"></tags-input>  
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it:

I've added to my html tag-input the following attribute:`on-tag-adding="emailcheck($tag)"`

And then in my JS file, I've added the function:

```
$scope.emailcheck = function (tag) {
        var addedEmails = tag.text.split(" ");
        for (var i = 0; i < addedEmails.length; i++) {
            var newEmailTag = { 'text': addedEmails[i] };
            $scope.emails.push(newEmailTag);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Now I just beed to remove the last tag, but that's not really a problem:
[image]